# Laravel 8 only working on developed computer and not other from live server

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, laravel-8

I have a laravel 8 app hosted on https://tonguelearner.com and it's running only on my Mac OS which I used to develop it. On other devices including mobile, only home page is working and other throws 404 server error.

Not sure how to identify the problem. Need some help.

Comment: Can you add more information. Your host (OS, host panle:cpanel, directadmin, ...), server (apache, nginx, ...).

Comment: Turn of debug mode for a publically available websites. Everyone can see things that they are not supposed to see otherwise. Also I don't see the problem you're describing https://tonguelearner.com/about is working fine for me (if we exclude the broken images which may indicate that you haven't ran `npm run mix` on your production correctly)

Comment: Server is Apache. Cpanel shared hosting. Debugger mode is set true.

Comment: Turn off debug mode. It exposes your environment variables if it's on

Answer (score 0):

If only home page works, it seems laravel can't handle routes except root of yout site. If your htaccess is over there and proper, enable mod_rewrite on apache;

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```